# Using Google Analytics in multiple websites, that are not owned by me. Is this possible?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm building a dashboard that uses data such as pageviews and time to load a page to process some trends.

To get such data, I could either build my own pageview tracking system, or just use something that's been already built.

I was thinking of using Google Analytics, and ask each customer to add my own Analytics tracking code to their website, but some aspects concern me:

- Privacy concerts

Some users might be concerned that by adding my own Analytics code, I will be able to access every bit of info tracked by it, not just pageviews and time to load pages.

- Using my own Analytics code in several sites

Is this possible at all? Or do I have to generate a different Analytics ID for each site?

Ideally, I'd rather ask the users to login to their Analytics account from my site, and then I'd be able to pull limited data from their Analytics accounts from an API. Similar to when someone registers to your app using Google/Facebook login. Is this possible at all with Analytics?

I'd love to be able to use Google Analytics but I'm not sure if it would be possible.. I'm concerned that by building my own tracking system, I could fail in some aspects as budget is limited, such as having a 100% uptime, making sure that the tracking system doesn't slow down customer's sites, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds similar to the service provided by Tableau, Klipfolio etc.
Anybody can pull data from anybody else's Google Analytics account through the API so long as they have the relevant permissions.

If your clients already have Google Analytics, you just need to get your program to interface with the API.